# Search DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable with 36000 columns minimum, 20000 rows min.  I have a hardcoded list of column names which I need to find in the datatable and perform some calculation on the values for each column.

e.g Sum of all rows for a particular column

I was thinking of using a simple foreach to find the column name and datatable.compute method to perform my calculation.

Is there a better way of achieving this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

I am using .Net 4.6 and VS2015

Comment: 36000 columns? Wow

Comment: What exactly do you do with `36000` columns and `20000` rows?

Comment: Yes, a better way would be to use a more appropriate storage medium than a grossly huge DataTable.

Comment: I create a CSV from the datatable. Simply split out the datatable as CSV.  The second part is to perform some calculations on the datatable. Any ideas or suggestions welcome.

Comment: So,besides having 36000 columns, you are trying to manipulate that data as a csv file instead of using sql queries?

Comment: My app does two things. First thing is to generate the CSV from a datatable. i have no problems with this. The Second thing (This question)

Comment: Once again, Why are you exporting the data to a csv instead of doing all the calculations using sql queries? For example, you wouldn't need to "find the column name", just `SELECT ColumnName FROM yourtable`

Comment: `I was thinking of using..` Have you *tried* that yet? I suggest trying it. Without a "I tried this, I expected A, but B happened" its very difficult to help you. Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

For more performance its good to use parallel methods.

This  link has a  sample for you to use  parallel and it is very Good to use it every where is possible.

At [this example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/efa3cf/parallel-foreach-vs-foreach-loop-in-C-Sharp/) you see how much will improve your speed.

Comment: but dont forget for edite ui parametrs inside parallel for or parallel foreach you need use invoking

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the performance difference between the Datatable.Compute and Foreach.

```
// Datatable.Compute sample
DataTable table;
table = dataSet.Tables["Orders"];

// Declare an object variable.
object sumObject;
sumObject = table.Compute("Sum(Total)", "EmpID = 5");
```

Below is a sample of foreach

```
// Foreach through DataTable
double sum = 0;
dt = ds.Tables["Orders"];
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    sum += System.Convert.ToDouble(dr["Total"]);
}
```